# MS Word and a multiple monitor setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

Does anyone know how I can have two Word documents open and visible at the same time on a multiple monitor setup?

In the default mode Office is displaying the documents at the same location. Any advice for me? I wish to have one document on a side of a monitor, and the other on the other side.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the two documents in two different windows, and drag one to the other monitor.

Comment: This works fine. Not sure why OP is having issues. Not that you need the +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have a 3 monitor system, with a Word document open on each monitor right now (I just started `winword.exe` 3 times). It is Office 2003 though. Maybe that's a difference with the 2007 version?

Comment: Not even necessary to open Word three times on 2007 - you can do as Josh suggested and drag them to respective windows.